# Enable Evil jump to work across all panes instead of only active pane

Tags: evil, buffers, motion

Is there a way to enable `evil-jump-forward` and `evil-jump-backward` to use the jump list of all panes instead of only the active pane?

In the gif below, here's what happens:

1. Start on left pane at bottom.
2. Go to beginning of the buffer on the left.
3. Move to the pane on the right at the bottom of the buffer.
4. Go to beginning of buffer on the right pane.
5. Press <kbd>C-o</kbd> for `evil-jump-backwards` four times.  The focus always stays in the pane on the right.

Is there a way to make the focus take into account panes as well?

[image: Emacs - jumping between panes]

Comment: Does Vim do this?

Comment: No.  From my fumbling in vim it appears evil matches the behavior of vim.

Comment: Then it's unlikely this will be implemented in Evil.

Comment: Right, I'm okay with a custom solution.